# Optimizing SQL cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and was asked to see if I could improve on some things.  I was able to clean a few things up, but this one has me stuck. These run super slow, but I am not sure how to fix it. Maybe a nested select?

Data is pulled from a few sources and pushed into a temp table which will then be used for a report...however cursors are how they do a lot of updates to clean the data.  They find records with null values, then look for similar records with populated cs_no to update the empty one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you

```
Declare CSUPDATE Cursor For 
    Select  Distinct cs_no
    From   #TEMP_EH 
    ORDER BY CS_NO
Open CSUPDATE
Fetch Next From CSUPDATE into @CS
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        Declare CS Cursor for
            SELECT  seqno
            FROM    #TEMP_EH
            WHERE   comment like '%'+@CS+'%' and 
                (cs_no is Null or cs_no = 'No Match Found')
                and comment is not null
            open cs
            fetch next from cs into @seq
            while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                begin
                    UPDATE      #TEMP_EH
                        Set   CS_NO = @CS
                        where seqno = @seq
                    fetch next from cs into @seq
                end
            close cs
            deallocate cs
        Fetch Next From CSUPDATE into @CS
    END
Close CSUPDATE
Deallocate CSUPDATE
```

EDIT:
Thank you for the advice, will be sure to be more detailed in my questions next time.

After my meeting started to create a test table and found a solution through trial and error.

```
    create table #derp(cs_no varchar(20), comment varchar(20))
    insert into #derp values (NULL, 'stuff')
    insert into #derp values (NULL, 'bacon2')
    insert into #derp values ('stuff', 'bacon3')

    select * from #derp

    UPDATE  a
    SET     a.cs_no = b.cs_no
    FROM #derp  A
    INNER JOIN #derp B on a.comment LIKE '%'+b.cs_no+'%'
    WHERE (a.cs_no is Null
            OR  a.cs_no = 'No Match Found')
            AND a.comment is not null

    select * from #derp
    --drop table #derp
```

Comment: The way to fix this is to stop using cursors. You have nested cursors here for an update. There is nothing you can do to make this acceptably fast. Look at this article http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ If you can post details like that we can help you with a set based (and super fast) approach.

Comment: One thing the article Sean liked to does not include but is useful for questions like this. Go to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and create a small runnable example of your query and link to it in your question, this will help leaps and bounds in letting other people optimize the query for you.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to update a the cs_no field, by searching for another record who has cs_no that exists within your comment. Its gross, but its for a report to link items who's data is incomplete/corrupted and linking fields gives the users a good guess to track down were our mystery item is. Part of my problem was not knowing the intention, but here ya go...

In the sample table, the first record contains (NULL, 'stuff').  The comment ('stuff') is then linked to the third record with a cs_no of 'stuff'. The update will then populate the first record to ('stuff', 'stuff')

```
    create table #derp(cs_no varchar(50), comment varchar(50))
    insert into #derp values (NULL, 'stuff')
    insert into #derp values (NULL, 'bacon2')
    insert into #derp values ('stuff', 'bacon3')

    select * from #derp

    UPDATE  a
    SET     a.cs_no = b.cs_no
    FROM #derp  A
    INNER JOIN #derp B on a.comment LIKE '%'+b.cs_no+'%'
    WHERE (a.cs_no is Null
            OR  a.cs_no = 'No Match Found')
            AND a.comment is not null
            AND a.comment <> ''

    select * from #derp
    --drop table #derp
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what this answer does and why it provides a solution to the specific problem. Code dumps are rarely ever of use to other people.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use cursors! If you can re-write it as set operations it will be much faster. Using cursors is death for performance on any sizeable dataset.

Comment: You are not new here and that should not be an answer, it should be a comment.

Comment: I was going to put it as a comment, but I thought that the point was sufficiently important about that usage of SQL that I promoted it. I cannot describe the pain I suffered over the years from the over-use of cursors. If you think I should delete, I will, and repost as a comment. Cheers!

Comment: Well, when you put it this way.. edit the question so I'll be able to undownvote